# Gulp — не удается запустить задачи последовательно. Как это сделать в Gulp 4?

Tags: gulp, сборка

Моя задача: 
1. Компилировать SCSS в папку build/ 
2. Скопировать полученный css в папку test

Пытаюсь сделать это по докам к Gulp 4 ([ссылка](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#gulpseriestasks)) - не срабатывает.

По команде gulp build - создается build/css/style.css, но не копируется в test 
Если запустить gulp copy:css отдельно - style.css копируется.

Код задач:

```
gulp.task('build', gulp.series(
  'clean',
  'css',
  'copy:css',
));

// gulp clean - очистка build
gulp.task('clean', (done) => {
  del( config.dest.root ); 
  done();
});

gulp.task('css', (done) => {
    gulp.src( config.src.cssEntry )
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'} )
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( config.dest.css ) );
    done();
});


gulp.task('copy:css', (done) => {
    gulp.src('build/css/**/*.*').pipe(gulp.dest('test/css/'));
    done();
});
```

UPD:
Если задать точный путь к style.css

```
gulp.task('copy:css', (done) => {
    gulp.src('build/css/style.css').pipe(gulp.dest('test/css/'));
    // gulp.src('build/**/*.css').pipe(gulp.dest('test/'));
    done();
});
```

Выдает ошибку

```
[09:42:34] Starting 'css'...
[09:42:34] Finished 'css' after 11 ms
[09:42:34] Starting 'copy-wp:css'...
tree
[09:42:34] Finished 'copy-wp:css' after 6.87 ms
[09:42:34] Finished 'default' after 33 ms
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: File not found with singular glob: D:/!!!DB_TopTools/OpenServer/domains/debug-gulp-wp/wp-content/themes/build/css/style.css (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (D:\!!!DB_TopTools\OpenServer\domains\debug-gulp-wp\wp-content\themes\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\glob-stream\readable.js:84:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
```